# Collection of Roger Penrose's scientific drawings

Tags: resource-recommendations, soft-question

Being fascinated by the scientific illustrations by Roger Penrose, I am searching for a more comprehensive collection of them. Preferably with concise captions explaining the context and principle of the drawings.

I am primarily looking for a book, but also websites. If anyone know of such publications, recommendations would be appreciated.

Comment: While it is not primarily a collection of drawings, his book “Road to Reality” does have a fair number of drawings.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it seems not about physics. Please note that res. recom. questions are restricted on Phys.SE.

Comment: I'd be interested in sich a book and website. Actually, some of his early drawings inspired the spin foams of LQG and the stringy calculus of monoidal/tensor categories.

Comment: @Qmechanic: It looks like physics. It may not be a 'hard' physics question but it is tagged as a 'soft' question. I'm voting to reopen.